# Can I use my Android phone as a bluetooth microphone (for Skype)?

Tags: skype

I do some international phone-calls. Gets annoyingly expensive. I didn't like a bigger Android mobile, so I got this small Motorola Fuzzout thingy.

Is there any way to link the Android phone as a Bluetooth microphone? I can run Skype on my Mac or Windows PC. However I'm not sure how to connect the devices that way.

Comment: brownie points if you make phone work as a camera for skype (skype does not support video calling on phone). Tripple points for doing that over USB.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the device you are on or can you provide a link to some info about it?  A Google search for "Motorola Fuzzout" didn't return anything relevant.  Also, why do you need the phone as an intermediary?  If you are using Skype on the computer why not just plug a mic and headphones into the computer or use a bluetooth headset?

Comment: This question asks basically the same thing (and has an answer, kind of): http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5796/can-an-android-phone-be-used-as-a-bluetooth-headset-speakers

Answer (score 2):

Is the Skype app available in your view of the Market?  If so, why not just make the call on the device itself (via Skype)?

Comment: It's not available because the model isn't supported ;)

Answer (score -1):

What you need is a A2DP headset, that's one that can send the Media audio (stereo) over BT. One such is the Jawbone Icon but a lot of the car handsfree gadgets use it too. I just verified this after updating the firmware on the Headset (which b.t.w. is not a stereo headset but a BT earpiece but has A2DP capability if updated).

You pair it and it should work. Test by opening a random youtube clip on the phone. If it works with youtube, it works with Skype. If you still get no sound open your BT settings and hold down on the row that represents your paired headset until a settings window is displayed, go to settings at the bottom and see if "Media Audio" is checked, if not check and try again. Should work now.