# Can an Android phone be used as a Bluetooth headset/speakers?

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, bluetooth-hsp

Is there a way to make an Android phone (HTC Desire HD) act as Bluetooth speakers or headset?

I'd like to use the phone as wireless headphones whilst watching a movie on a computer (running Ubuntu).

Comment: It looks like there are several apps that can do wireless speaker (over Wi-Fi though, not seeing any that do bluetooth), but none so far that do wireless headset.  This Wi-Fi speaker app advertises Linux support: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Duse+android+as+wireless+pc+headset&pcampaignid=APPU_fA3EVKPnEPf8sAS-uYKQCA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Feb 2011, the Bluetooth API only supports pairing with the Android device as the master.

Reference: [Stack Overflow - Use Android device as a headset for another device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892506/use-android-device-as-a-headset-for-another-device)

Comment: Comment by Dennis Mathews to the linked answer - *Anyway being a master or slave has nothing to do with what it can or cannot do, the roles in bluetooth are symmetrical - it is the supported profiles that determines what it can or cannot do*

Comment: Partially solved, because newer APIs can perform it in the future, or specific APIs or some kind of hack can perform it...

Answer (score 4):

Here's a [XDA article](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-play-music-or-podcasts-over-bluetooth-on-your-car-stereo-without-a2dp-support/) by Mishaal Rahman that basically says:

Even without A2DP profile on Android (which is not implemented even in Android 8 yet), you can do a low-quality Bluetooth streaming via Hands-free Profile (HFP) to Android from another Android phone (sorry iPhone owners!)

Install [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) and a [AutoVoice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autovoice&hl=en) plugin on the source phone, and create the following Tasker profile:

```
Profile: Reroute Audio (192)
State: BT Connected [ Name:BMW 15384 Address:* ]
Enter: Anon (199)
A1: AutoVoice Ctrl BT [ Configuration:Enabling Headset Sound Timeout (Seconds):0 ] 

Exit: Anon (204)
A1: AutoVoice Ctrl BT [ Configuration:Disabling Headset Sound Timeout (Seconds):0 ]
```

Warning: I have not tested this myself.

Warning: quotation about HFP audio quality:

> Note: because the Hands-Free Profile is not meant to send high-fidelity audio streams, the audio quality of your music will suffer. This is just the nature of the Hands-Free Profile and there’s nothing you can do about it without either upgrading your stereo’s Bluetooth to bring A2DP support or to stream through another peripheral.

Answer (score -1):

I must be missing something, why do you want the phone to do it?

You'd be better off using a USB Bluetooth chip (they cost less than £5) on your PC and a Bluetooth Headset (I've got a superb one that lets me plug in any headphones I want, 3.5 stereo jack so would take any little speakers as well).

Comment: Well as the PC already has Bluetooth and the phone already has Bluetooth and produces decent quality sound, I'd like a way to use what I've got rather than buy a seperate Bluetooth headset.

Comment: I stand by my answer - buy a BT headphone adapter about £10 inc shipping. Then you can pair it with the pc and the phone...Leveraging the BT technology as its designed to be used. You'll have much less trouble configuring and finding apps or drivers.

Comment: Does the Desire really have decent speakers?

Comment: The Desire HD has a lot better sound than the Desire (I've had both), but I'd be using it with headphones. The idea is for when sound out loud when watching a movie would disturb others in the room.

Comment: "Don't do that" is rarely a good answer, and it's rarely a good idea to tell people what to do with their hardware. Here's a perfect example where this question is really useful: old Android-based car player. It costs a fortune to replace and still can be a perfect speaker for a newer tablet/phone.