# Is it possible to add an audio bluetooth profile to my phone?

Tags: bluetooth, headset, bluetooth-audio

I want to make my phone act as a bluetooth speaker/headset because the audio jacks connection on my laptop is kinda broken (won't play audio on both ears unless the headset plug is midway inserted). Add to that the fact that the audio coming out of my laptop's speakers aren't too loud. My phone, however, fills in that gap by having quite good and loud audio and the headset jack on my phone isn't messed up like the one my laptop.

So upon thinking of ways to do this, I realized that I could add a bluetooth profile to my phone so that the laptop will be able to detect it as a bluetooth headset. However, I couldn't find any info about doing this.

I'm using an SE ST17i and I'm rooted so rooted solutions are applicable. I hope someone can help me out.

P.S. I know of the AirFoil approach but would rather prefer my above approach if possible because I don't like keeping my wifi on all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [my answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/19421/11343) to a [similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/19161/11343) - the problem is that within the Bluetooth AD2P profile (for stereo quality audio) Android phones aren't designed to be a "sink" (a receiver of media) only a source. You're right in that this is a limitation of the Bluetooth stack on your phone, but so far the info I've found says that trying to alter the stack comes with moderate amounts of [pain and compromise](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=739794). Perhaps you're more adventurous than I?

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. Based on what you've linked, it seems my only ray of hope is from using a CM-based rom.