# Using rooted android device as a bluetooth speaker

Tags: root-access, bluetooth, speaker

I want to use my rooted Android phone (Moto G) running 4.4.4 Kitkat with Bluetooth 4.0 as a bluetooth speaker, is there any way to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19161/how-to-stream-audio-from-pc-to-android-device-over-bluetooth