# Use android phone as bluetooth receiver in car

Tags: bluetooth, music, a2dp

In my car I have my old Android phone as the GPS and music player. I was hoping to use it as a receiver for my calls coming to my other phone and any bluetooth devices around it streaming music. Is there a way to do this? I have searched Google thouroughly.

Comment: How old is it? Android's Bluetooth stack took a long time to mature and it was very limited until a late 2.x version of Android.

Comment: Did you find any information about this?

Comment: A link for this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=780500 - we are looking for A2DP receiver capability in Android.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5796/can-an-android-phone-be-used-as-a-bluetooth-headset-speakers

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible with most Bluetooth Android phones  but you would have to root your device and find a ROM  with source code  like `CyanogenMod` and rewrite the Bluetooth driver.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is still no bluetooth server implementation available for android devices.

The connect as "music player" part of your question could be realized via WiFi, using the **SoundSeeder Music Player** app ([soundseeder.com](http://soundseeder.com) or [forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2392672](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2392672)

You need to connect your devices via "WiFi direct" or the portable hotspot of your device. Then you can use your old phone as wireless speaker for your main device. The app also supports google music and online radio stations.

[image: soundseeder image]