# Can I use an old phone as a bluetooth headset and dialer?

Tags: bluetooth

I'd like to use one of the new 7" tablets that will have cell service as a phone. I would like to leave it in my backpack and use something smaller to send and receive calls.

I think I should be able to recycle an old Android Phone for this purpose. I figured there is some kind of Bluetooth stack (Bluez?) that just needs to be configured the right way. The hardware should be all there. The best I could find thus far was [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20630/use-android-phone-as-bluetooth-receiver-in-car) and the links therein.

I saw some dedicated devices on Alibaba that do this; and I have seen people do this in China. But I haven't seen any such devices in the US. I could settle for a dedicated device, but recycling an old smartphone would be more useful.