# Make an old Android into a mobile device to answer calls away from desk

Tags: bluetooth, calls, headphones

We got a new stationary Bluetooth phone system at work with no headsets. Is it possible to make my old Android into a mobile device to answer calls away from my desk?

Comment: Please see this similar question and it's answers https://android.stackexchange.com/q/5796/2241